# How does "spreading-with-determinacy" compare with Cichon's diagram?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, descriptive-set-theory, cardinal-characteristics

For $\mathbb{A},\mathbb{B}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\omega^\omega)$, say that $\mathbb{A}$ *spreads onto* $\mathbb{B}$ iff there is some $F:\omega^\omega\rightarrow\omega^\omega$ such that $F[A]\in\mathbb{B}$ whenever $A\in\mathbb{A}$. Write "$\mathbb{A}\trianglerighteq\mathbb{B}$" for "$\mathbb{A}$ spreads onto $\mathbb{B}$."

Each cardinal characteristic in [Cichon's diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicho%C5%84%27s_diagram) $\mathfrak{x}$ is defined as "The smallest cardinality of an element of $\mathbb{X}_\mathfrak{x}$" for some $\mathbb{X}_\mathfrak{x}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\omega^\omega)$. I'm curious how the $\mathsf{ZFC}$-provable *cardinality* relationships between the $\mathfrak{x}$s compare to the $\mathsf{ZF+DC+AD}$-provable *spreading* relationships between the $\mathbb{X}_\mathfrak{x}$s. Specifically:

- Is it the case that, for all $\mathfrak{x},\mathfrak{y}$ in Cichon's diagram, $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash\mathfrak{x}\le\mathfrak{y}$ implies  $\mathsf{ZF+DC+AD}\vdash \mathbb{X}_\mathfrak{x}\trianglelefteq \mathbb{X}_\mathfrak{y}$?
- Is it the case that, for all $\mathfrak{x},\mathfrak{y}$ in Cichon's diagram,  $\mathsf{ZF+DC+AD}\vdash \mathbb{X}_\mathfrak{x}\trianglelefteq \mathbb{X}_\mathfrak{y}$ implies $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash \mathfrak{x}\le\mathfrak{y}$?

As positive evidence, [Paul Larson showed](https://mathoverflow.net/a/394616/8133) that $\mathsf{ZF+DC+AD}\vdash\mathbb{X}_\mathfrak{b}\triangleleft \mathbb{X}_\mathfrak{d}$, so the "spreading-under-determinacy" picture agrees with (and in fact strengthens) the "cardinality-under-choice" picture in this instance.

I'm particularly interested in the behavior of either of the triples $\mathsf{add}(\mathcal{B}),\mathsf{cov}(\mathcal{B}),\mathfrak{b}$ or $\mathsf{cof}(\mathcal{B}),\mathsf{non}(\mathcal{B}),\mathfrak{d}$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the $\sigma$-ideal of meager sets, since [there is a $\mathsf{ZFC}$-theorem about each *triple*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicho%C5%84%27s_diagram#Diagram) which isn't a consequence of any of the provable "simple inequalities" - I don't know how (if at all) I'd expect this more complicated relationship to be reflected on the "spreading"-side.

Comment: Wouldn't it be spreading *into*, rather than spreading *onto*?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I had in mind (and still do) the image of spreading butter onto bread, so that if you consider "most" of the butter it covers "most" of the bread. (Of course both bread and butter here are Baire space, but that's fine since "bread and butter" is frequently used to refer to the Baire necessities.)

Comment: But the definition doesn't require any sort of coverage. $\{\varnothing\}$ spreads "onto" any other class which includes the empty set, for example the full power set of the Baire space.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That's true, but I'm only looking at "largeness" classes here. If we consider $\emptyset$ large then anything should indeed be large.

Comment: @NoahSchweber "Baire necessities"? $-\infty$ if I could downvote comments.

Comment: @bof Clearly the solution is to upvote and hope for an overflow error. :P

Comment: @bof: That pun was unBaireable...